# Identity the available range numbers when two range numbers are overlap

Tags: php

If I have an existing range:

```
1-10
11-50
```

Then I will enter a new range from 1 - 60, How could I detect that the new range to be added overlaps to the previous entries? And how can I get the available range? In this case the available range is from 51-60.

Does anyone here have a great idea on this?

Thanks for helping.

Here's my current code:

```
$saved = array(
                            array(
                                    "start" => 1,
                                    "end"   => 10
                                ),
                            array(
                                    "start" => 10,
                                    "end"   => 50
                            )
                        );
            $new_range = array(
                                "start" => 1,
                                "end"   => 60
                            );
            $usable_range = array();
            $previous_from = 0;
            $previous_to = 0;
            foreach($saved as $value)
            {
                $range_start = 0;
                $range_end = 0;
                if($previous_from<$value['start'])
                {
                    $previous_from = $value['start'];
                }
                if($previous_to<$value['end'])
                {
                    $previous_to = $value['end'];
                }
                if($previous_from<=$new_range['start'])
                {
                    if($previous_to<$new_range['end'])
                    {
                        $range_start = $previous_to+1;
                        $range_end   = $new_range['end'];
                        $new_range['start'] = $range_start;
                    }
                 }
                else if($previous_from>=$new_range['start'])
                {
                    if($previous_to<$new_range['end'])
                    {
                        $range_start = $previous_to+1;
                        $range_end   = $new_range['end'];
                        $new_range['start'] = $range_start;
                    }
                }
                $usable[] =     array("range_start"=>$range_start,"range_end"=>$range_end);             
            }
```

Comment: I have tried it manually but it is not efficient. The output is not correct when there are huge of range.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried, please?

Comment: How are you working out the ranges at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call every interval (min,max)

1) Sort your list of intervals by their `min`.

2) Check to see if any `max` is greater than the next entry over's `min`. If they are, create the interval that is the smaller of their mins and the greater of their maxes, and add it back into the list in place of those two.

3) Whenever you get a new interval, binary search into the list to add it, sorted by `min`. Then, using similar logic as in 2), attempt to merge it with the entry one below and one above until no more merges are possible.

---

EDIT: A few changes.

First, since we're using integers not floats, if you have an interval like 1,10 and 11,20 then there is no 'gap' between the 10 and 11 - so we should consider this to be one larger interval, 1,20. Reflect this by, instead of checking to see if `max > next min`, if `max >= next min - 1`.

Second, if you want to find all intervals formed by overlap when merging a new interval into your list of intervals:

1) Since your list of intervals is known to be in a state where it is sorted by `min` and also sorted by `max`, binary search into it to find the lowest min just above your new min and the highest max just above your new max.

2) Iterate over min, max, min, max... etc in your array that are between your new min and new max. Below the lowest min, above the highest max and between each max/min you can compute the interval that is in the 'gap' there, and return them in e.g. an array.

---

For example if your list of intervals contains 13,16, 21,24 and 31, 38 and you want to calculate the non-overlap of the new interval 1,30:

1) We binary search into our list and find that 13 is the lowest min above 1 and 24 is the highest max above 30.

2) We iterate like so:

- Between our min and the lowest min is 1 and 13 - so this forms an interval 1,12 (inclusive bottom, exclusive top). Add onto the return array.
- Between max and the next min is 16 and 21 - so this forms an interval 17,20 (exclusive on both ends). Add onto the return array.
- Between max and our max is 24 and 30 - so this forms an interval 25,30 (exclusive bottom, inclusive top). Add onto the return array.

Comment: Thanks Patashu, I don't really understand in step number 2. Could show it in mathematical way or actual way. I like this idea.

Comment: @John Rey Flores If you have an interval (mina,maxa) and an interval (minb,maxb) they overlap if maxa > minb or mina > maxb (if you've sorted by min already, you only need to bother checking one of these, since the other will never be true). And if they overlap, the interval that spans all of the a and all of b is composed of min(mina,minb),max(maxa,maxb). e.g. if you have 1,3 and 2,4, they overlap because 3 > 2 and min(1,2),max(3,4) is 1,4. Make sense?

Comment: Yes it make sense, what if I have a number 1,10 and 11,50 and 1,60 how could i calculate that only 51 to 60 in not overlap? does this question is clear?

Comment: @JohnReyFlores Hmm, I see, you want to compute specifically the interval(s) left over after subtracting other intervals. That's trickier, I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @John Rey Flores I updated my answer to include an example run.

Answer (score -1):

Finding overlap can be described as finding an intersection. Likewise finding the available range can be described as finding the difference. One way of doing this would be treating these sets as arrays and using the array_intersect [1] and array_diff [2] functions.

That is all I can come up with given your details.

[1] - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

[2] - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: What if the intervals were of `float`s?

Comment: The OP didn't post any code samples when I first responded but I still think my answer can solve the question. I'm looking at it from the approach of set theory. It really doesn't matter what is in the sets. Seeing the sets do contain numbers though a range could certainly be iterated through to populate arrays. Once the arrays are populated the array_intersect and array_diff function could be used.

Comment: interval arithmetic != set arithmetic. You can pretend to do interval arithmetic with set arithmetic if the intervals are discrete and you populate them with every value inside of them, but it's a slow hack.